# Getting xop include object using nodejs

Tags: node.js, attachment, mtom, xop

I need to download the xop include object which is coming in response of one SOAP service using NodeJS.

I am able to get the response using soap library, but need to understand how to download the file

```
         <ns2:result xsi:type="ns0:DocumentDetails" xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/model/erpIntegrationService/types/" xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/svc/types/" xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/model/erpIntegrationService/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ns0:Content>
               <xop:Include href="cid:3418224f-0d44-4e65-a8fb-a2f8bfb3b87d" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/>
            </ns0:Content>
            <ns0:FileName xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ns0:ContentType xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ns0:DocumentTitle>TEST.pdf</ns0:DocumentTitle>
            <ns0:DocumentAuthor>testAuthor</ns0:DocumentAuthor>
            <ns0:DocumentSecurityGroup>Attachments</ns0:DocumentSecurityGroup>
            <ns0:DocumentAccount xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ns0:DocumentName>Test.pdf</ns0:DocumentName>
            <ns0:DocumentId>11758236</ns0:DocumentId>
         </ns2:result>
      </ns0:getDocumentForDocumentIdResponse>
```